# PyQt5 закрытие всех диалоговых окон вслед за главным

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при закрытии главного окна диалоговые не закрываются. Как решить эту проблему?

Пример **основного окна**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import test_dialog


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: test_dialog.main())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Диалоговое окно:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    w.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#import test_dialog
from test_dialog import Dialog                                               # +++


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))



class MyWin(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: test_dialog.main())
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.testDialog)                       # +++

    def testDialog(self):                                                      # +++
        self.dialog = Dialog(self)                                             # self
        self.dialog.show()        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**test_dialog.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):                         # Dialog
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                # parent
        super().__init__(parent)                                    # parent
        self.setupUi(self)


def main():
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    w.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: А для задания функций, работы над элементами диалогового окна, как в главном окне, что нужно сделать? Предполагаю, что ещё один класс, но как его вызвать?

Comment: @SecorD если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте `Новый вопрос`.  Опишите, что вы хотите сделать, что вы пробовали и что у вас не получается. Приложите пример демонстрирующий проблему.